# QName is accessible from more than one module - OpenJDK 11?

Tags: java, openjdk-11, qnames

I have a **QName** reference problem in my project in eclipse, using JDK 11.

```
The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
```

I have looked for all class references, and if you can help me with this problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqTsV.png

Comment: I’m guessing your project uses an old library that forces a dependency on an explicit definition of Java’s standard XML classes.  Whatever that library is, your best bet is finding a newer version or finding an alternative which has been more recently maintained.

Comment: You should add more of the stack trace.